# Performace with multiple localized strings for uppercase/mixed case variants vs a single string and use strtoupper() in PHP?

Tags: php, localization, zend-framework2, translate, view-helpers

## Background Info:

I am using Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) on a LAMP stack running PHP 5.3, and the built in translate functionality out of the box and it works exactly as I would expect.

For those that are unfamiliar here is an example:

```
<?php echo $this->translate("Company")?>
```

As far as my understanding goes of how it functions, it is a view helper that can be used to translate strings on any of the view .phtml files. It grabs the appropriate localized string (in this case "Company") from the language files (.PO files created using [PoEdit](http://poedit.net/) ).

I have about 250 localized strings and I would prefer to reduce duplicates for maintainability for translation, but if performance will suffer I will opt for performance to squeeze every bit of speed out of ZF2. I use these translate functions all over in my views wherever UI text is displayed, and I don't want to abuse the helper if there is a more efficient ways of doing things.

## The Core Question

Which of the following will yield better performance? Is strtoupper more expensive than an additional call to the translate helper?

```
<?php echo $this->translate('Company')?> //# Mixed Case Uses String #1

<?php echo $this->translate('COMPANY')?> //# UPPERCASE Uses String #2

<?php echo strtoupper( $this->translate('Company') ) ?> //# String #1
```

*Note: Since PoEdit stores COMPANY and Company as two separate strings, the first two will require two distinct calls to the translate helper, and two distinct strings to be translated.*

## Concluding Notes

While I am familiar with ZF2 and PHP, I am green behind the gills as a 'self-taught' programmer, so when it comes to writing performant php code I am not sure what to look for and appreciate any insight to help start off on the right foot.

Comment: I would guess `strtoupper` is faster, but benchmark it and see. If you want the word uppercase for purely presentational reasons, remember you can do this with CSS instead.

Comment: Brilliant! I don't know why that had not occurred to me to use CSS for client side presentation, I kind of feel silly now :) . Thank you Tim! I have not had much experience in benchmarking, are there any tools you suggest? I am using PHPStorm and XAMPP but if there are better tools suited for benchmarking I will be grateful for the advice~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Tim suggested, instead of complicating things on the server side transform the text on the client side using CSS.

CSS

```
.uppercase{ text-transform:uppercase; }
```

HTML

```
<span class="uppercase"><?php echo $this->translate('Company')?></span>
```